# Зачем использовать SSG и SSR, если есть useEffect?

Tags: nextjs, next

В моем понимании SSG и SSR нужны для лучшей seo оптимизации.

Вот пример:

[image: index.tsx]
[image: main.tsx]
[image: результат в браузере]

И все ок, мы взяли данные из сервера, и показали их пользователю в виде html.

Но если мы перепишем на useEffect:

[image: index.tsx]
[image: main.tsx]
[image: результат в браузере]

Результат в браузере точно такой же самый, как если бы мы использовали getStaticProps. У нас точно так же видна html страница, с данным в виде html.

Тогда зачем нужно использовать getStaticProps, если результат такой же?

P.s Мой вопрос может быть странным, но хотелось бы без негатива.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Замените ваши скрины текстом. Читать не возможно и скоприровать тоже, что бы воспроизвести...

Comment: В инструментах разработчика у тебя уже html после рендеринга. А что бы посмотреть что на самом деле получил браузер используйте ctrl-u. И там будет пустой html

Comment: а, понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В инструментах разработчика у тебя уже html после рендеринга. А что бы посмотреть что на самом деле получил браузер используйте ctrl-u. И там будет пустой html –

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).